# virtualbox windows 7 vm not booting with bridged connection

Tags: virtualbox

I just updated my ubuntu workstation to 13.10 from 13.04. Before the update, my windows VM with VirtualBox worked just fine. Now, it won't boot up and it lists this as the error:

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-eth1' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

It works if I change it to connect via NAT, however, I need it to be a bridged connection otherwise I don't have any internet/network access. I've been googling for a while now and can't find any solution that works.

Here is a printout of my ifconfig:

ktate -> ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:51:fb:42:fe:23
          inet addr:192.168.50.198  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a51:fbff:fe42:fe23/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:134639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:97302877 (97.3 MB)  TX bytes:11497520 (11.4 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:618506 (618.5 KB)  TX bytes:618506 (618.5 KB)

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info and I'll be happy to reply immediately with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completely removed and re-installed virtualbox and rebuilt the VM. used the same VDI and everything works great now